# friends_of_friend_ids(user) function error (trying to determine 2nd degree connections)

Tags: python

The function friends_of_friend_ids(user) is supposed to find the friends of a friend. The function should count a user's friends following some rules (see below). I'm following an example in the book 'Data Science from Scratch: First Principles with Python" and there was an errata in one of the previous functions. Now I have to adjust friends_of_friend_ids(user) to make it work again.

foaf = friend of a friend

**Correct code (I think)**

```
users = [
    {"id": 0, "name": "Ashley"},
    {"id": 1, "name": "Ben"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Conrad"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Doug"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Evin"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Florian"},
    {"id": 6, "name": "Gerald"}
]

#create list of tuples where each tuple represents a friendships between ids
friendships = [(0,1), (0,2), (0,5), (1,2), (1,5), (2,3), (2,5), (3,4), (4,5), (4,6)]

#add friends key to each user 
for user in users:
    user["friends"] = []

#go through friendships and add each one to the friends key in users
for i, j in friendships:
    users[i]["friends"].append(j)
    users[j]["friends"].append(i)    

#friends of friend projects
def friends_of_friend_ids_bad(user): 
    return [users[foaf]["id"]
        for friend in user["friends"]
        for foaf in users[friend]["friends"]]

def not_the_same(user, other_user):
    return user["id"] != other_user["id"]

def not_friends(user, other_user):
    return all(not_the_same(friend, other_user) 
        for friend in user["friends"])
```

**Function I can't figure out**

```
def friends_of_friend_ids(user):
    return Counter(users[foaf]["id"]
        for friend in user["friends"]
        for foaf in users[friend]["friends"]
        if not_the_same(user, foaf) and not_friends(user, foaf)]
```

Comment: So what doesn't work? What was the correction made to the first part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the last `]` in `friends_of_friend_ids()` with `)`, and `foaf` in the loop is an integer, not a dictionary, so you need to resolve that back to a user dictionary:

```
def friends_of_friend_ids(user):
    return Counter(users[foaf]["id"]
        for friend in user["friends"]
        for foaf in users[friend]["friends"]
        if not_the_same(user, users[foaf]) and 
           not_friends(user, users[foaf]))
```

You have a similar error in `not_friends()`; you need to resolve ids to full user dictionaries:

```
def not_friends(user, other_user):
    return all(not_the_same(users[friend], other_user) 
        for friend in user["friends"])
```

The generator expression essentially does this:

```
counter = Counter()
for friend in user["friends"]:
    for foaf in users[friend]["friends"]:
        if not_the_same(user, users[foaf]) and not_friends(user, users[foaf]):
            counter[users[foaf]['id']] += 1
```

Note how the loops nest in the same order they are listed in the generator expression.

With the above two fixes the code works:

```
>>> for user in users:
...     print('User: {}'.format(user['name']))
...     print(friends_of_friend_ids(user))
... 
User: Ashley
Counter({3: 1, 4: 1})
User: Ben
Counter({3: 1, 4: 1})
User: Conrad
Counter({4: 2})
User: Doug
Counter({5: 2, 0: 1, 1: 1, 6: 1})
User: Evin
Counter({2: 2, 0: 1, 1: 1})
User: Florian
Counter({3: 2, 6: 1})
User: Gerald
Counter({3: 1, 5: 1})
```

Comment: File "/Users/marlon/Desktop/test.py", line 73, in <module>
    print friends_of_friend_ids(users[0])
  File "/Users/marlon/Desktop/test.py", line 68, in friends_of_friend_ids
    for friend in user["friends"]
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 534, in update
    for elem in iterable:
  File "/Users/marlon/Desktop/test.py", line 70, in <genexpr>
    if not_the_same(user, foaf) and not_friends(user, foaf))
  File "/Users/marlon/Desktop/test.py", line 60, in not_the_same
    return user["id"] != other_user["id"]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @user2469211: looking into this. It'd be helpful if you told us more about how the data structures changed.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I don't exactly understand your question sorry. I think if you take all the code I posted you should be able to replicate.

Comment: @user2469211: the error is in the `not_the_same()` function, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. When I try to print (print friends_of_friend_ids(users[1])), I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" pointing to the print statement.

Comment: @user2469211: Are you using Python 3 perhaps? `print()` is a function in Python 3, not a statement.